# Generar certificado autofirmado con OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial para generar un certificado autofirmado con los comandos que me muestra

https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/documentacion/como_empezar#credenciales-en-webpay

Pero resulta que el primer y segundo comando,se ejecutan a la perfección, pero cuando intento ejecutar el comando numero 3 me muestra lo siguiente

#### Comando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No uses el backslash y pon todo en una sola línea. Eso es, nada más

Comment: @Anthony ¿Conseguiste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una serie de pasos a seguir para crear tu certificado autofirmado.

```
cd C:\xampp\apache\bin
```

Estando en este directorio ejecutamos los siguientes comandos para crear el certificado.

Generar clave privada

```
openssl genrsa -out C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\local.key 4096
```

Generar csr

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -out C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.csr\local.csr -key C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\local.key -config C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf
```

Crear certificado, crt

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 3650 -in C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.csr\local.csr -signkey  C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\local.key -out  C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\local.crt -extensions req_ext -extfile C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf
```

[Aquí como hacerlo también](https://medium.com/@jonas.damher/crear-certificado-ssl-autofirmado-v%C3%A1lido-en-6-pasos-en-xampp-802bd11509d)